# Extracting files from directory via loop

Tags: python

I am running a loop which needs to access circa 200 files in the directory.

In the folder - the format of the files range as follows:

```
Excel_YYYYMMDD.txt
Excel_YYYYMMDD_V2.txt
Excel_YYYYMMDD_orig.txt
```

I only need to extract the first one - that is YYYYMMDD.txt, and nothing else

I am using glob.glob to access the directory where I specified my path name as follows:

```
path = "Z:\T\Al8787\Box\EAST\OT\\ABB files/2019/*[0-9].txt"
```

However the code also extracts the .Excel_YYYYMMDD_orig.txt file too

Appreciate assistance on how to modify code to only extract desired files.

Comment: Please provide a [reprex].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to loop through the files returned by `glob.glob(path)`. For example if

`files = glob.glob("Z:\T\Al8787\Box\EAST\OT\\ABB files/2019/*[0-9].txt")`

you could have

`cleaned_files = [file for file in files if "orig" not in files]`

This would remove every item in files that contains the substring `orig`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should incorporate a split function into the code:

```
var=path.split('whatever letter separates them')
```

Then print out that variable.